# Some windows don't fit on 1024x600, what can I do?

Tags: gnome, resolution

I read on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Netbook_Edition) that the netbook edition of Ubuntu was discontinued and that it is now integrated into the main distribution (as of 11.04).

I tried 11.04 on my new Samsung NC110-A06AU with 10.1" 1024x600 display. Most things worked out of the box, but some (like backlight power control) needed some [coercion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10131416&postcount=36) before they began to co-operate.

One thing that seems to be an ongoing problem is the resolution.

At 1024x600, most of the dialogue boxes run off the bottom of the screen, including the update manager. I have tried 11.10 beta 1 and it has the same problem.

Is there any way to fix this, or at least make it more usable? (I suspect not). Given the recent rise in popularity of netbooks, do you think Ubuntu will include a low-resolution-friendly version in the near future?

How well does KDE deal with these low resolutions? I noticed KDE Plasma has a netbook interface. Is it worth switching for that?

Comment: That's not a really problem at all, That's because put simply that's the resolution of the netbook nothing you can do about it. Since the KDE taskbar/panel/etc. is more akin to the Windows 7 taskbar probably KDE dialog boxes won't be off screen, now is it worth it? only you will know that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately there are still plenty of pieces of software that do not take low resolution screens into account when designing their interfaces.

One workaround you can do when a window doesn't fit is to click and drag on any area of the window on it while holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key down, this will let you move the window up so that you can at least click the buttons on the bottom of windows.

Comment: Windows key on Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 LTS on Dell Mini 9

Answer (score 3):

As a fellow netbook user, I developed a "hack" or workaround (of sorts) for software like this.

It only works if you're running Unity 3D though.

So, hit the shortcut <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to get the workspace switcher - you can now drag and drop the windows around as you please.

Example:

[image]

*Despite the 11.10 in the screenshot, it **does** work in 11.04*

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52716/maximize-windows-to-physical-screen-when-using-a-virtual-resolution-w-xrandr) - it is possible to set up the desktop so it's "virtual size" is larger than the physical screen and the "virtual desktop" can be scrolled up and down to see the parts of the screen which do not fit.

Actually, I'm going to try it on my original EeePC with 800x480 resolution :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your backlight issue:

It's a known issue, that Samsung has some problems on Linux. There is a package in PPA that trys to fix that.

https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa

After I installed those PPA packages on my Samsung N150 most of the problems were fixed.

Comment: I am going to down-vote you unless you explain how that PPA is going to make his netbook's screen bigger :)

Comment: @Sergey No it's OK. I clarified the answer (needs peer review) to show he is answering the question on backlight control which I indirectly asked in my OP.