# Always on top sidebar : how to make all applications think the screen is less wide than it is

Tags: unity, gtk, rss

I really miss the google-desktop linux sidebar. The sidebar was a gtk widget that could be positioned on the right and had the option to add many gadgets to it. The great feature of the sidebar was that all applications would stay out of its way . Full screen for other applications was always acutal size of monitor - minus - the area occupied by the sidebar.

I got used to having rss feeds to a bunch of places on the sidebar open all through the day while I worked.

How can I achieve this effect with Ubuntu 12.04 onwards.

Is there a way to trick all applications except one from thinking that the full screen is everything but the sidebar. I can get chrome or conky to serve as the sidebar "widget" updating feeds ..but I do not know how to have all other windows stay out of its way.

Answer (score 3):

After reading this [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52716/maximize-windows-to-physical-screen-when-using-a-virtual-resolution-w-xrandr) by [Ryan Reich](https://askubuntu.com/users/6118/ryan-reich) i could achieve this with compiz.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I have conky running in the right and when a window is maximize... does not cover my conky configuration.

In my example, I have this Desktop resolution ***"1920x1080"*** and my conky use 270 px in the right.

**1)** Firs you need to install the **Compiz configuration settings manager** package.

[image: Install via the software center]

**2)** Open **Compiz configuration settings manager** and go to *"General Options"* > *"Display Settings"* Tab.

[image]

[image]

**3)** Edit these settings according to your needs, in my example *"uncheck"* the *"Detect Outputs"* and in "Outputs" settings, create 2 entries. The first one for the area that the applications "can see" to maximize.

my case is **1650x1080-270+0** *(1920 - 1650 = 270px to conky in the right)*.

The other entry is you full resolution, my case **1920x1080**.

Then go to the **"Overlapping Output Handling"** setting and choose **"Prefer smaller output"**.

**4)** press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and execute:

- `compiz --replace`

Now the windows when are maximized left the 270px free for conky to be displayed.

If you want to change to your full resolution... change the **"Overlapping Output Handling"** setting for **"Prefer larger output"**.

Hope this will helful.