# Change Desktop Area used by Maximized Windows

Tags: compiz, window

Right now I have an embedded terminal that occupies the bottom 100 or so pixels of my screen. This is super convenient for me, but unfortunately, whenever I maximize a window, it of course covers up the terminal.

Is there any way to make an application when it maximizes, to only take up the desktop area that does not include the very bottom of the screen where the terminal is? Also, it would be very nice to prevent any window, even those not maximized from entering this part of the screen.

If anyone knows how to make this happen, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Parts of this answer comes from: [I'd like to prevent maximize from covering one third of the screen](https://askubuntu.com/a/35143/9598)

> Maximumize may be useful for that case instead of Maximize. Which is
>   included in the CompizConfig Settings Manager and will ***"Maximumize
>   windows (resize them to fit the available screenspace)"***
>
> In your case, Maximumize will fit the window's size in order to use
>   the maximum available screen space in the active work space and this
>   way, windows in screen containing the pidgin, conky, and other
>   window-like applications will be dodged by the Maximumized window.

**Maximumize comes from the `compiz-fusion-plugins-extra` package.**

Good luck!

BTW: You may need to set your own key bindings in order to make this work. I used [Alt]+M and it works fine for me.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Window rules plugin in CCSM

[image]

In the 'Above' match add the terminal application you are using

[image]

This will keep the terminal always on top of any other window. You can also adjust window sizes from there.