# Restricting maximized window bounds in gnome

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

I am creating a side bar with a chrome app which acts as a dock.

I would like to restrict the size of all maximized windows in order that they will no go under my side bar.

[image]

There is [some solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194479/change-desktop-area-used-by-maximized-windows) with compiz settings manager ccsm, but not available for gnome-shell.