# Virtualbox windows guest taskbar always visible

Tags: windows, virtualbox, taskbar

At work, I use Ubuntu Linux 14.04, and most of the software I use has a compatible/alternative on Linux, but some corporative software run only on Windows. Because of it, I have installed VirtualBox with a Windows guest to run it. I like seamless mode, but I'm looking for a way to configure Compiz or any other alternative/creative mode(without change from Compiz) to make the windows guest taskbar always visible, even if I maximize a window on Ubuntu.

I made a search on Compiz plugins but couldn't find one to do it. Any ideas?

I'm looking for something to not have to resize the ubuntu windows manually.

I've heard about program MaxMax on windows that do exactly what I want, but nothing on Ubuntu Linux.

I'm not considering to change from Compiz to kwin.

Answer (score 0):

I found an 90% answer of this question, based on that post:  [I'd like to prevent maximize from covering one third of the screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35079/id-like-to-prevent-maximize-from-covering-one-third-of-the-screen)

Reading the answer of user Ryan Reich I made the steps below:

- Open Compiz configuration tool (ccsm)
- Went to General Options > Tab Screen Definitons

  - As my windows(Virtualbox) taskbar is on right(in opposite to Unity bar) I added a second output like this: 1920x1080+0-45 (45 is the size of windows taskbar)
- Then, as the post above, disableed autodetection of outputs and enabled "prefer smaller output".

Then the new windows, when maximized stay in front of windows taskbar.

The remain problem to solve is: occasionaly I have to close VirtualBox. After I restart it, new process, it pass to respect the new rules and wont be maximized using the whole screen. It also respects the 45 pixes at right.